# bgcolor on the 10th candle from the current candle

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to use bgcolor to paint the background of the 10th candle from the current candle.

Here is what I have:

```
// Define the number of candles to count back
candlesToCountBack = 10

// Calculate the index of the 5th candle from the current candle
candleIndex = bar_index - candlesToCountBack

// Condition to check if the current candle is the 5th candle
isTenthCandle = bar_index == candleIndex

bgcolor(color = isTenthCandle ? color.red: na)
```

I was expecting a red background on the 10th candle, but this code doesn't result in anything. What could be off, or is it even possible?

Comment: Pine Script™ code generated by ChatGPT results in garbage. Versions are mashed & frequently the generated output will not compile. When it does compile it is usually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offset` argument of the `bgcolor()` function to move the bgcolor to the left or right.

```
bgcolor(color, offset, editable, show_last, title, display) → void
```

> ***offset (series int)*** Shifts the color series to the left or to the
> right on the given number of bars. Default is 0.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

bgcolor(barstate.islast ? color.red : na, -10)
```

[image]

Please note that, your script will be executed on each bar. So, without `barstate.islast` or some other condition, all bars except the last 10 will be highlighted.